# How to change main URL in reason of navigation at iframe?

Tags: javascript, browser, browser-history, html5-history

I tried this, but users need to click back button twice, one to change the back the hash and another to back the iframe content:

(TypeScript)

```
this.iframeApp.load(() => {
    if (this.sameDomain()) {
        window.location.hash = this.iframeApp[0].contentWindow.location.toString();
    } else {
        window.location.hash = this.iframeApp.prop('src');
    }
});
```

And at start:

```
var url = window.location.hash;
if (url.length > 1) {
    url = url.substring(1);
} else {
    url = this.settings.default;
}
this.openPage(url);
```

I think History Api won't help. I need something that works on IE9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.iframeApp.load(() => {
    if (this.sameDomain()) {
        window.location.replace(window.location.toString() + '#' + this.iframeApp[0].contentWindow.location.toString());
    } else {
        window.location.replace(window.location.toString() + '#' + this.iframeApp.prop('src'));
    }
});
```

By using the *replace()* method, you can't go back to thre previous url, so your users will only need to push the back button once.

Comment: Worked, but I needed to remove the hash before concat the new one. var urlWithouthash = window.location.toString().replace(/#.*$/, "");

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention that :-)